# Querying Across Multiple Tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have four tables in MySQL database. Protein, Terminusmodifications, Nterms and Kws. 
Kw_id is a foreign key in Terminusmodifications table. terminusmodifications_id is a foreign_key in the Nterms table. protein_id is a foreign key on the Nterms table which corresponds to the Proteins table.

I have a user inputted kw_id. That should be able to give me a Terminusmodifications_id which I can then use on the Nterms table. Using that on the Nterms table, I can identify a protein_id which I can use to query the proteins table. I want to use this query on an extraction of the proteins table that I've already gotten that looks something like this:

```
@protein = Protein.joins(:searchnames).where("searchnames.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")
```

So I was thinking:

```
@protein = @protein.joins(:nterms)....
```

Something along these lines, but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax. I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.0.0

Here are what the tables look like:

```
Proteins:
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ac              | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| molecular_type  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| entry_type      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dt_create       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dt_sequence     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dt_annotation   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| definition      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sequence        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mw              | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| crc64           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| aalen           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | unknown |                |
| data_class      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chromosome      | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| band            | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| species_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meropsfamily    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meropssubfamily | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meropscode      | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
Nterms:
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| protein_id              | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pos                     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at              | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at              | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| import_id               | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| idstring                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isoform_id              | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| terminusmodification_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| seqexcerpt              | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Terminusmodifcations:
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nterm       | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| cterm       | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| subcell     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| psimodid    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| display     | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| kw_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ac          | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Kws:
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ac          | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The associations between the models:

The Proteins model:

```
  has_many :nterms, -> { uniq }
```

The nterms model:

```
  belongs_to :protein

  belongs_to :terminusmodification
```

The terminus modification model:

```
  has_many :nterms
  belongs_to :kw
```

The kw model:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :proteins
  has_many :terminusmodifications
```

**Solution found**

```
@protein = @protein.joins(:nterms => {:terminusmodification => :kw}, :cterms => {:terminusmodification => :kw}).where("kws.name = ?", params[:modifications])
```

Comment: It is unclear whether your associations are has_one or has_many. It would be helpful if you could include your code in the relevant models showing this.

It is also unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. It seems like you want to find a single protein from a single Kw. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. I'll update the question to add the associations. And yes. I want to find proteins from a single kw. That kw would associate with a terminus modification which associates with an nterm which associates with a protein

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has_many through:` to get associations of associations

Kw model:

```
has_many :nterms, through: :terminusmodification
has_many :proteins, through: :nterms
```

Then you should be able to access all proteins related to a Kw by:

```
@kw.proteins
```

Comment: Oh I didn't add the associations of kw to my edit. I am going to give your solution a try though.

Comment: Hmm I just realised that nterm actually belongs to a protein instead of a protein belonging to an nterm. I'm not sure how to do it with belongs_to

Comment: Right so a protein can have many nterms. But an nterm only has one protein.